# Not able to download maven dependencies in one linux server but in another linux server it's working fine

Tags: java, maven, networking, firewall

I’m not able to download the maven dependencies in one of the linux server(lets say A), it got stuck at downloading and same is working in another linux VM(lets say B). It got stuck at below -
`Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/distra/switch/plugins/cartridge-validation/5.0.3-11-1/cartridge-validation-5.0.3-11-1.pom`

I'm exporting below variables -
`export MAVAN_HOME="/apps/workspace/tools/apache-maven-3.8.6" export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')" export PATH="${PATH}:/apps/workspace/tools/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin:$JAVA_HOME"`

My A VM should be able to download maven dependencies like B.

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /apps/apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.el8_6.x86_64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Probably a connectivity problem from the server/vm.

Comment: Firewall in between?